# Real roots of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

A friend gave me this equation which I have trouble finding the real roots. $$x^9+3x^6+3x^3-16x+9=0$$ One can easily see that 1 is a root then with the help of Horner's method this can be simplified. However I am looking for an elegant solution if possible not just to use a computer to do that madness calculation. I reduced it to $$x^3+1=2(2x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$ I don't have any  useful attempts.

EDIT: After several tries I think I found something useful. After getting to this form $x^3-2(2x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+1=0$ we might notice that it's similar to the equation that you provided me in the answers namely$$(x-1)(x^2 +x-1)=x^3 - 2x+1=0$$ Now in order that this to give me the solution, we must have that $-2(2x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=-2x\, $ If we cube both sides we return to $x^3 - 2x+1=0$ (the solutions) Is this a repeatedly loop in the equation? Can this be useful?

Comment: What is Horner's method ?

Comment: basically a shortcut to devide a polynomial when you know one root. see:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method

Comment: So what do you get when you divide by $x-1$ ?

Comment: You could first use Descartes' rule of sign to ascertain how many (positive and negative) real roots you even have.

Comment: That's easy to do $E(x)=(x-1)(x^8+x^7+x^6+4x^5+4x^4+4x^3+7x^2+7x-9)$

Comment: I understand you need to find them explicitly. But it would help to know how many of them are there. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x^3+1)/2$. Then $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with inverse $g(x)=(2x-1)^{1/3}$. As you already remarked, the original equation can be written as
$$((x^3+1)=2(2x-1)^{1/3}.$$
This equation is equivalent to $f(x)=g(x)$ or $f(f(x))=x.$

Now note that if $f(x)=x$, that is $x^3-2x+1=0$ then $f(f(x))=x$ which implies that $x^3-2x+1$ divides the given polynomial. After the division, we obtain the factorization
$$(x^3-2x+1)(\underbrace{(x^3+1)^2 + 2 x^4+3x^2+(x+1)^2}_{\geq 0} + 7) \tag{*}.$$
So it remains to solve 
$$x^3-2x+1=(x - 1) (x^2 + x - 1)=0$$ 
and the desired real roots are $x_1=1$, $x_2=(-1-\sqrt{5})/2$,  and $x_3=(-1+\sqrt{5})/2$ .

P.S. In my first answer I used maple to find the factorization $(*)$.

Comment: Did you find that using a computer?

Comment: Yes. But I did not use the computer to show that the third factor is always positive

Comment: @Sonkun as you've seen, the other real roots are non-trivial. So I'm not sure if you'll be able to find an elegant form for your problem

Comment: Can you take a look at the edit?

Comment: @Sonkun I read your edit and I think I found a "human" solution to the factorization.

Comment: Could you please explain this: Now note that if 
f(x)=x

, that is 
x
3
−2x+1=0
x3−2x+1=0
then 

f(f(x))=x
which implies that 
x
3
−2x+1
x3−2x+1
divides the given polynomial?

Comment: Looks like this problem is pretty common: http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/Coffins/coffinsmain.html

Comment: @Sonkun. If $f(x)=x$ then $f(f(x))=x$. Therefore the roots of the the polynomial $P(x)=f(x)-x=x^3-2x+1$ are also roots of the polynomial $Q(x)=f(f(x))-x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial can be factored by considering the product of 
$$(x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c) \cdot (x^6 + \alpha x^5 + \beta x^4 + \gamma x^3 + \delta x^2 + \eta x + \mu).$$
With a little bit of effort it can be found that 
$$(x - 1) (x^2 + x - 1) (x^6 + 2 x^4 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^2 + 2 x + 9) = 0.$$
The real roots are then obtained as $x=1$ and roots from $x^2 + x -1=0$.

Comment: My friend is not  a dog! I don't really care If you don't believe me. There are a lot of exercises for admission in college, he got it from there. (I am already in college that's why he asked me)

Answer (score 0):

One way to attack this problem is by estimating number of real roots. For that we can use Descarte's Rule of Signs. So, for 
$$f(x) = x^9+3x^6+3x^3-16x+9$$
We have $2$ change of signs, hence the number of positive real roots are $0$ or $2$, but since we know $f(1)=0$, therefore we have $2$ positive real roots.

Now, $$f(-x) = -x^9+3x^6-3x^3+16x+9$$
We have $3$ change of signs, hence the number of negative real roots are $1$ or $3$

So, $f(x)$ has either $3$ or $5$ real roots

That's as far you can get without getting your hands dirty with ardous calculations involving estimation of coefficients as done by both Leucippus and Robert Z. But if you take your first case as $f(x)$ having $3$ real roots, then you essentially land at Leucippus's answer, and you're in luck as that works, in this case.